# yii validation rule

Tags: php, validation, yii

I have a situation.
I have three categories category1,category2 & category3.
I need to write my own validation rules in yii such that atleast one is required.
How to write that?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/

Comment: please read the question twice. This is not same as given in the doc. Those validations are for single/multiple attributes. Here I dont want same validation for all my categories. Its kind of "anyone required" type of validation

Comment: Reading it twice does not help ;). Please explain more, and possibly show some code. Are the "categories" attributes of another model? Or are they related models? How is the category information stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trying the [atleast validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/atleastvalidator/)?